# when i run the shell script by terminal then it's working fine, bt when i run in jenkins then it give the error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, ssh

This my shell script:

```
scp -r -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mbox /home/mbox/Desktop/qtworkspace/mbox_gui/Debug.tar.gz mbox@111.11.11.118:/mbox/deployment/mbox_gui/
```

...........................

```
Started by user Vikash
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Copy_Mbox_Gui_Files/workspace
next nodes: [][workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6656909050940929806.sh
+ scp -r -i /home/mbox/.ssh/id_rsa_mbox /home/mbox140/Desktop/qtworkspace/mbox_gui/Debug.tar.gz mbox@111.11.11.118:/mbox/deployment/mbox_gui/
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

..................
On Ubuntu

Comment: The problem is right there "Host key verification failed" ssh couldn't verify the host key of the system you are ssh-ing to. You need to fix that (or tell ssh to ignore it).

Comment: It is strange though. Could it be that the Jenkins user cannot "see" the file in `~/.ssh/id_rsa_mbox`?

Comment: When you execute it on shell, do you do so as user mbox? because `~` could have another meaning there.

Comment: Host key is incorrect!!!

Comment: directory /home/mbox/.ssh/  in my system

Comment: if my Host key is incorrect then , how could work shell script by ubuntu terminal . (by terminal it's working fine)

Comment: Is this really a programming Q. for S.O.? I think more appropriate to http://superuser.com OR http://askubuntu.com . Voting to close. Good luck.

Comment: There might be path issues ... Usually jenkins create its user in os... Just remove `~` with absolute path `/home/*` and try

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins uses its own user. There are two ways of achieving what you want to achieve.

1) From regular terminal emulator, login as the Jenkins user and ssh to the target host and create the host key.

2) Use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

I vote for #2.